# React Native- Using Hermes with Flipper disabled on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, podfile, react-native-hermes, fbflipper

I'm having a hard time using Flipper. I commented it out in Podfile while     `hermes_enabled => true`. I ran pod install agin and build the app but it crashed upon launch.
When I set Hermes to false, it was build successfully.

Is there a way to disable Flipper & keep Hermes true and app builds successfully?

Answer (score 4):

For react-native v0.70.1 I did the following

1. Remove `react-native-flipper` from `package.json`. Maybe I think you need to remove other packages that depend on the flipper. But I didn't
2. Set in ios/Podfile

   `:flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.disabled`

   instead of

   `:flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled`
3. Remove `node_modules`
4. Run `yarn` or `npm install`
5. Clear old data:

- 5.1 Run `cd ios`
- 5.2  Run command  `pod deintegrate && pod install`
- 5.3 Run `cd ..`
- 5.4 Run `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
- 5.5 Run `cd..`

Clearing old data is really important, I even restart my MacBook

I hope this helps you